# Is there any root finding algorithm that is differentiable?

Tags: roots, newton-raphson, neural-networks

I need to integrate a root finding algorithm in a neural network. For that, and in order to be able to perform backpropgation I need the algortihm to be differentiable. Is there any method/ algorithm to get a root finding that is compatible with a neural network, i.e is differentiable?

Comment: Do you know about automatic differentiation of code ?

Comment: Yes but how can use automatic differentiation with a root finding algorithm? I want to use the output of the neural network that provides a function that need a root finding algorithm to provide the target of the neural network. So I want to learn the neural network to predict this specific root for that I need a root finding algorithm (if there is any) that is compatible with automatic differentiation during the backpropagation.

Comment: You can try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_Turing_machine